# How do I make buttons function in Maya using Python?

Tags: python, scripting, maya

I am writing a script to create a little text adventure in Maya using Python.  It is for a coding class.  I can get two windows to pop up with their own buttons, but I want the first window to create the second window and so on.  A side note- I cannot get additional text aside from the buttons to show, would be helpful to the story.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

'''
this Script allows you to begin a text adventure!
'''

def jmWindowTales (*args) :
    # Make a the first window
    print "Enjoy the journey"
    window = cmds.window( title="Window Tales", iconName='Short Name', widthHeight=(300, 100) )
    cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )
    cmds.button( label='Begin Your Journey')
    cmds.button( label='Observe')
    cmds.button( label='Close', command=('cmds.deleteUI(\"' + window + '\", window=True)') )
    cmds.setParent( '..' )
    cmds.showWindow( window )
jmWindowTales()

def jmScene1 (*args) :
    # The first scene in our story
    window = cmds.window( title="You approach the bar", iconName='Short Name', widthHeight=(300, 100) )
    cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )
    cmds.button( label='Inquire about work')
    cmds.button( label='Leave Tavern', command=('cmds.deleteUI(\"' + window + '\", window=True)') )
    cmds.setParent( '..' )
    cmds.showWindow( window )
jmScene1()
```

I tried `cmds.button( label='Begin Your Journey', command=('cmds.window("jmScene1")') )`  and a few other variations.  As it stands, the second window pops up first rather than being prompted by "begin your journey" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heavily recommend to use classes for this type of operations. Or at least one function to reduce reduntant tasks. Your problem is that you call cmds.showWindow() for all windows. So either you create all windows you need but do not call showWindow or you simply use `jmScene1` as button cmd like this:

```
cmds.button(label="Begin your Jurney", command=jmScene1)
```

But I suggest to use an approach like this:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

class MyWindow(object):
    def __init__(self, title="Title", iconName="Short Name", windowDimension=(300, 100), buttonData = [("A", None), ("B", None), ("C", None)]):
        self.title = title
        self.window = None
        self.iconName = iconName
        self.windim = windowDimension
        self.buttonData = buttonData
        self.buildUI()
        
    def buildUI(self):
        if self.window is not None and cmds.window(self.window, q=True, exists=True):
            cmds.deleteUI(self.window)
        self.window = cmds.window( title=self.title, iconName=self.iconName, widthHeight=self.windim)
        cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True)
        for data in self.buttonData:
            btn = cmds.button(label=data[0])
            if data[1] is not None:
                if data[1] == "Close":
                    cmds.button(btn, edit=True, command=self.closeCmd)
                else:
                    cmds.button(btn, edit=True, command=data[1])
                                    
    def closeCmd(self, *args):
        cmds.evalDeferred(self.close)            
    def close(self):
        cmds.deleteUI(self.window)

def scene1(*args):
    SC1 = MyWindow(title="Window Tales", iconName='Short Name', windowDimension=(300, 100), buttonData=[('Inquire about work', None), ('Observe', None), ('Leave Tavern', "Close")])
    cmds.showWindow(SC1.window)
                
WT = MyWindow(title="Window Tales", iconName='Short Name', windowDimension=(300, 100), buttonData=[('Begin Your Journey', scene1), ('Observe', None), ('Close', "Close")])
cmds.showWindow(WT.window)
```

Here I use a class to simplify the process. If you have quite similiar setups this makes the process less repetitive and easier to maintian.